# Android SDK vs Corona SDK

Tags: android

Привет! Я бы хотел спросить у вас, как вы относитесь к мультиплатформенным фреймворкам типа Kivy, Corona. В чем они уступают Java и Android SDK. Какая думаете,что перспективнее изучать, если особого интереса к играм нет.

Comment: Вопросы, подразумевающие ответы, основанные на мнениях, а не на фактах - оффтоп. Картко - если надо быстро и как-нибудь под все платформы - то используйте кросплатформенные решения. Если надо качественно и гибко - то нативную.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб "Быстро" - это только для небольших приложений, с минимумом требований к GUI, и при наличии хорошего опыта с данной технологией. В опыт входят и наработки - никакое умение нагуглить чужой сторонний код для решения задачи не заменит уже готовый свой исходник в копилке. P.S. Отказался от C++ Builder XE 10.2 и FMX в своем проекте (Windows / OS X).

Comment: @Rou1997, ну да, я просто опустил "при прочих равных") Всё сказанное применимо только при наличии гигантского опыта)

Comment: нативные инструменты имеют все ключевые преимущества перед кросплатформенными и существенные настолько, что если есть какая то возможность не использовать кросплатформенное решение, ею стоит воспользоваться.  Единственное разумное оправдание кросплатформенного решения: нужно выпустится на все платформы, но нет опыта под какую то из них  и денег, чтобы нанять аутсорс. При этом нужно заранее быть готовым к тому, что изделие будет хуже нативных по многим параметрам. Делать ставку на опыт только в кросплатформенном движке неразумно.

Comment: Если бы с кросплатформенными решениями все было бы хорошо, то все бы писали на таких движках, кому хочется держать дублированный штат сотрудников под каждую платформу (я имею ввиду фирмы, которые могут себе позволить применять лучшие решения). По факту доля кросплатформенных приложений на рынке ничтожна, а из успешных я знаю только 2GIS (QT)

Answer (score 1):

Уступают в количестве документации, сообществе, сторонних туториалов, исходников, библиотек (одним словом "экосистема").

В них самих и их SDK больше багов и выявляются и исправляются позже, опять же из-за слабого комьюнити и того, что у их создателей меньше денег на штат сотрудников, чем у Google.

Отсутствие некоторых нативных возможностей, вернее их поддержка есть включая интеграцию с Java, но только через "костыли" (bridge), что не очень удобно.

**Главная проблема - это GUI**, он на каждой ОС свой и различается больше чем что-либо другое. Кроссплатформенный фреймворк предоставляет свой GUI, а он гораздо хуже стандартного, а с экосистемой стандартного несовместим (или опять же "костыли", да и зачастую некий виджет - особенно сторонний - есть только для одной ОС и не имеет схожих аналогов для другой - и что делать? портировать самим и убить на это дни и даже недели?)

Усугубляет то, что именно на мобильных ОС выше требования к GUI, он почти всегда "кастомный".

Короче говоря, в идеале обучение нужно начинать с нативных инструментов, затем осваивать кроссплатформенные, и это будет не самый узкий кругозор и хорошее дополнение к своему резюме. А если только что-то одно, то все-таки лучше натив. Хотя, рынок таков, что можно начать почти с чего угодно, и все равно со временем так или иначе достигнете успеха. Инструменты - это не главное.

Comment: все же нельзя сказать, что инструмент не главное, если он "жрет" ресурсы (скорость работы, оперативная память, место на постоянном хранилище, заряд и тд.) и при этом дает заведомо худший результат (существенные ограничения использования возможностей платформы-хоста)

Comment: @pavlofff Если инструмент "жрет" ресурсы, но вы будете сохранять ему верность, то рано или поздно найдете тех, у кого достаточно ресурсов - с ними и будете работать. И вот ведь что - если у людей есть деньги хорошо платить вам (или фирме за продукт, которая, в свою очередь, платит вам) то и деньги на железо найдутся. А вот скорость разработки - важна, пожалуй, везде.

Comment: @pavlofff Например, игры, которые в конце 1990-х годов писались с применением новейших технологий и под крутое для тех времен железо - продаются до сих пор, и современное железо они нагружают более чем скромно. "Змейка 3D" там была, ее продает Alawar под названием "Большой Змей", и сама команда разработчиков жива и тоже продает ее, русские, но живут в США, сайт на английском. А те игры, которые в те же годы писались все еще под DOS, на современной Винде даже не запустятся без DOSBox.

Comment: что ж .. вы меня не убедили, что кросплатформенные решения имеют какие то преимущества, что через 10 лет приложение древнее по  всем параметрам не будет "жрать" на мощном железе того времени - я вижу, что происходит сейчас и пользоваться ими планируется сейчас, но они существуют, значит есть какие то сторонники - пусть они и переживают, когда уже железо потянет

Comment: @pavlofff А я и не убеждал именно про кроссплатформенные и тем более какие-то конкретные, ваш комментарий был абстрактный - и мой тоже. P.S. А железо все-таки дешевеет и сейчас, я слежу ситуацию по самому дешевому МК в магазине "чип и дип", месяц назад был STM32 за 50 руб, теперь в продаже появился STM8 (новых моделей, информация в интернете по которым датируется 2016 годом) за 30 руб.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я все понял. Дискуссия так же принесла мне много нового!

Comment: не стоит отвечать на вопросы, [которые лучше не задавать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ваше мнение - ваше право. Но на один голос против мне по-боку. А в целом сообщество нормально к этому относится. А как иначе.. Ведь сами разработчики этой "короны" никогда не расскажут об ее недостатках и о том, что иногда надо использовать не их инструмент - просто умолчат. И где брать истину.

Comment: вы явно не поняли, о чём я говорил. вопрос — оффтопик. отвечать на него не стоило **именно поэтому**. вне какой-либо зависимости от того, «хорош» или «плох» ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Форум правильный, тэги правильные = не оффтопик по определению. Вот когда код на VB.NET с тэгом C#, это еще можно так назвать, хотя если сделать скидку на то, что в тэге VB.NET всего 1.5 вопроса...